# how to access a models data from a view in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

I have a model named person:

```
 var person = Backbone.Model.extend({
      initialize: function(){
        console.log('cool');
      },
      defaults:{
          names:['a','k','d','s','h','t']
      }
    })
```

Now I have a view:

```
var person_view = Backbone.View.extend({
   model : person,
   output: function(){
      console.log(this.model.get('names'))
   }
});
```

Created an object of the view:

```
var obj = new person_view()
```

Try to access names:

```
obj.output()
```

But I got this error:

```
TypeError: Object function (){ parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'get'
```

Can you show me how to do things properly?I've only just started getting to know backbone.js so please bear with me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to initialize your Model before you could access it :

```
var person_view = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.model = new person();
    },
    output: function(){
        console.log(this.model.get('names'))
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of passing the model when you `extend` the view, you'll want to pass it when you construct a new view:

```
var person_view = Backbone.View.extend({
  output: function(){
    console.log(this.model.get('names'))
  }
});

var obj = new person_view({
  model : new person()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "person_view" can not access any model (which is expected by that view) ,as no model is created yet, when you are declaring "person_view"  and calling its function.
First make a model then pass it to view when declaring that "person_view".

```
var model_person_for_view= new person();
var obj = new person_view(model:model_person_for_view);
obj.output();
```